# Android: Sharing a big file from my app (image, document, etc., ...) without creating a copy in a cache folder/temp file

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-contentprovider, reader

I am trying to share a file (any type of file) from my app with another app in the phone (via the Share menu, for example), or preview it in the phone's default app, but I need to do this without creating a copy of the file in a temp or cache folder to then use the path to create an intent, as it is commonly done.

The difference is that I already have the file in the phone, but it's stored in a custom file system of sorts (this is the app we are working on, and among other things it encrypts the file, which is why the file is not in a regular folder in the phone). I can easily get the file's bytes, create a reader, etc; but so far I have only found the usual way to do what I need: create a temporary file, write the bytes to it, then create an intent with the path to this file, and so on.

Am I missing something?

Is there a way to pass, instead of the path to the file, other kind of abstraction that tells the other app or to Android, to use it to get the file (the bytes?) from a reader or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can easily get the file's bytes, create a reader, etc; but so far I have only found the usual way to do what I need: create a temporary file, write the bytes to it, then create an intent with the path to this file, and so on.

That has not worked in several years, if by "create an intent with the path to this file" you mean something like using `Uri.fromFile()`.

> Is there a way to pass, instead of the path to the file, other kind of abstraction that tells the other app or to Android, to use it to get the file (the bytes?) from a reader or something similar?

A `Uri` is not a file. The `Uri` that you supply via `EXTRA_STREAM` on an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` does not have to point to a file. In fact, it's not *supposed* to point directly to a file.

It is supposed to point [to a `ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers).

Now, a common `ContentProvider` implementation for `ACTION_SEND` is [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider), which is a `ContentProvider` that knows how to stream the contents of files on the filesystem. However, you do not have to use that — you can create your own `ContentProvider` that streams content from other sources.

You can [download for free an older edition of one of my books](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.6-CC.pdf). It has a lot of material on `ContentProvider`, including ~50 pages in two chapters focused on how to implement custom providers. You would be using the streaming-style API more than the database-style API. Off the cuff, [the `Pipe` example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/ContentProvider/Pipe) is probably the closest to what you would be doing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your book @CommonsWare, and for the clarification on `ContentProviders`; I will read and try using your points.

Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the Pipe example creates a linear non seekable stream of bytes for the receiver? If so, is there a way to provide a seekable `ParcelFileDescriptor` or is that not supported by the API?

Comment: @PeterJankuliak: "Is it correct to say that the Pipe example creates a linear non seekable stream of bytes for the receiver?" -- that is a nice description! "is there a way to provide a seekable ParcelFileDescriptor or is that not supported by the API?" -- I never found a solution for that, after years of searching. It is possible that something was added for this in the past few releases, as I stopped worrying about the problem and may have missed something.

Comment: @CommonsWare given your activity on this topic, I think you may be interested in hearing that we got the proxy file descriptor approach working as well. The code might still need some polishing, but it works. It can be found [here](https://github.com/equalitie/ouisync-plugin/blob/c4955bbe4355e36beea1e4296da7001f2c8c5b24/android/src/main/kotlin/ie/equalit/ouisync_plugin/PipeProvider.kt#L53-L72). Just to recapitulate: this approach enables the apps that consume the content to get the file size without reading it all as well as seeking through the file (useful e.g. when watching big videos).